# Is there a name for the function of a semicircle?

Tags: functions

Recently I've learned many different names for different types of functions... but I've been wondering, is there a name for *this* type of function?

$\sqrt{x - x^2}$

Comment: I don't think that looks like a semicircle.

Comment: It's something that's been bugging me, just because I've read all these formal definitions of functions, and I want to categorize this one, but I'm not sure if there's a name for it other than just "semicircle."  Maybe I'm not even sure why I'm asking this question, because the answer really is that obvious. I'd like to know what it is though, regardless, since I felt confused enough to post a question about it.

Comment: @JonathanHebert But it is, as it is $\sqrt{ (\frac12)^2  - (x - \frac12)^2}$

Comment: Unless you use numbers between 0 and 1 for x, I think the results are imaginary numbers. So this isn't the semicircle function.

Comment: So basically, from what I'm thinking, there isn't a name for a function of a semicircle other than just "semicircle." But in this particular case the function can only have fractional values or 1 or 0, so what is this then? An arc?

Comment: You mean to write $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so people are tring to point out to you that you have written the wrong expression.

Comment: @JHance I think we can agree that circles/semicircles have a constant radius, no?

Comment: I can't think of anything beyond "algebraic function" that names that - and that's a *very* wide class of functions (including anything writable with radicals, sums, and products). I'd just call it a semicircle.

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for this.  It's fine to just label it $S(x)$ or whatever.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Yes, and it does have constant radius. If graphed between $0$ and $1$ it is the semicircle centered at $(1/2,0)$ with radius $1/2$.

Comment: @Jhance Yes, I see. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots and lots of different functions, and there is no name for most of them.
There are some classifications and descriptions that can be useful to describe a function; for example your function is an algebraic function and a square root of a polynomial and its graph (over the interval $[0,1]$) is a semicircle.
Apart from very few examples (the sine function, the exponential function, the characteristic function of a given set…) you should give a formula if you want to refer to that particular function.
Names (consisting of words) are good for describing functions, not for identifying them.